# Assigning instances in os.walk in python

Tags: python, instances

I am trying to create a walker that goes through directories. Here are the inputs and outputs which I have partly working. I am using a test directory but I would like this to be done on any directory which is leading to some problems.

```
[IN]: print testdir  #name of the directory
[OUT]: ['j','k','l']  #directories under testdir

[IN]: print testdir.j
[OUT]: ['m','n']  # Files under testdir.j
```

Here is the code so far:

```
class directory_lister:
    """Lists directories under root"""
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        self.ex = []
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            self.ex.append(item)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.ex)
```

This returns the directories and files but I have to manually assign the names of the directories.

```
testdir = directory_lister(path/to/testdir)
j = directory_lister(path/to/j)
etc
```

Is there a way to automate instances such that:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(/path/to/testdir/):
    for x in dirs:
        x = directory_lister(root) #I want j = directory_lister(path/to/j), k = directory_lister(path/to/k) and l = directory_lister(path/to/l) here.
```

Can there be a:

```
class directory_lister:
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        self.j = directory_lister(path + os.sep + j) # how to automate this attribute of the class when assigned to an instance??
```

The code above is wrong as the object x only becomes an instance but j,k,l have to be defined manually. Do I have to use another class or a dictionary with **getattr** but I always run into the same problem. If any extra information is required please ask, I hope I made this clear.

UPDATE 2

Is there a way to add other complex functions to the DirLister by Anurag below? So when it gets to a file say testdir/j/p, it prints out the first line of file p.

```
[IN] print testdir.j.p
[OUT] First Line of p
```

I have made a class for printing out the first line of the file:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, path):
        """Read the first line in desired path"""
        self.path = path
        f = open(path, 'r')
        self.first_line = f.readline()
        f.close()

    def __repr__(self):
        """Display the first line"""
        return self.first_line
```

Just need to know how to incorporate it in the class below. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the desired interface and functionality of `directory_lister`?

Comment: `os.walk` already lists all the directories and files, so what is the point of `directory_lister`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, the functionality is for conveniently listing the directories under a root directory. So you just specify the root directory then the rest becomes very easy to view.

Comment: That isn't even close to answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want sub-dir to be accessible like a attribute, you can achieve that two ways

- Go thru list of files and create variables dynamically
- Hook into attribute access and correctly return listers as needed

I prefer second approach as it is lazy, better and easier to implement

```
import os

class DirLister(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self._list = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            var = super(DirLister).__getattr__(self, name)
            return var
        except AttributeError:
            return DirLister(os.path.join(self.root, name))

    def __str__(self):
        self._load()
        return str(self._list)

    def _load(self):
        """
        load once when needed
        """
        if self._list is not None:
            return
        self._list = os.listdir(self.root) # list root someway

root = DirLister("/")
print root.etc.apache2
```

output:

```
['mods-enabled', 'sites-80', 'mods-available', 'ports.conf', 'envvars', 'httpd.conf', 'sites-available', 'conf.d', 'magic', 'apache2.conf', 'sites-enabled']
```

You can improve this to have better error checking etc

**Code explanation:** this is basically a recursive listing of directory, so a `DirLister` objects lists files under the given root and if some variable is accessed with dotted notation it returns a DirLister assuming that that attribute is a folder under the root. So if we try to create `DirLister` class step by step it will be more clear

1- A simple `DirLister` which just lists files/folders under it

```
class DirLister(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self._list = os.listdir(self.root)
```

2- Our simple lister just list files one level deep, if we want to get filers under subfolders we can hook into `__getattr__` which is called with varname when `obj.varname` is used. So if our dir-lister doesn't have a attribute named varname we assume user is trying to access that directory under given root, so we create another DirLister whose root is `root+subdirname`

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        var = super(DirLister).__getattr__(self, name)
        return var
    except AttributeError:
        return DirLister(os.path.join(self.root, name))
```

Note: first we check base class for that attribute because we don't want to treat all variable access as sub-dir access, if there is no such attribute hence `AttributeError` then we create a new DirLister for sub-folder.

3- To improve code so that we don't list all folders even if user did not ask for them, we only list when user requires, hence a `load` method

```
def _load(self):
    if self._list is not None:
        return
    self._list = os.listdir(self.root) # list root someway
```

so this method lists dir if not already listed, and this should be called when we finally need it e.g. while printing the list

Edit: as asked by OP here is the alternate method of recursively list whole tree though I would strongly recommend against it

```
import os

class RecursiveDirLister(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self._sublist = []
        for folder in os.listdir(root):
            self._sublist.append(folder)
            path = os.path.join(root, folder)
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                continue
            # add it as attribute, assuming that dir-name is valid python varname
            try:
                sublister = RecursiveDirLister(path)
            except OSError:
                continue#ignore permission errors etc
            setattr(self, folder, sublister)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._sublist)

etc = RecursiveDirLister("/etc")
print etc.fonts
```

output:

```
['conf.avail', 'conf.d', 'fonts.conf', 'fonts.dtd']
```

Comment: Nice. The underlying assumption of using directory names as attributes falls down when you have a period in a directory name though (as I noticed when testing this out).

Comment: Thank you! This does the job very well, I am beginner would you mind just talking me through the code to better understand it?

Comment: @GordonBroom not even dot, anything thing which is allowed in filenames but is not a valid python variable name will give error

Comment: Thank you for explaining was very helpful. Is it possible to make it more complex by printing the first line of a file. So testdir/j/n would return, print testdir.j.n, 'First line of n'? Would that require the use of the first way (the non-lazy one)? Also how to make the class iterable?

Comment: @Jimmy yes you apply similar logic to do whatever you want to do in attribute access, e.g. if var name is a number use it to read files and return values

Comment: @Anurag I am having trouble with assigning my File class to files to the var.     if os.path.isfile(var) == True:
                    var = File()
          else:
                    return var

.But I still get no testdir.afile as not a directory. Can someone please help me out? (I am trying to implement UPDATE 2 in the question in your code).

Comment: @Jimmy may be ask it as a separate question

Comment: Have posted here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524311/readline-feature-in-directory-lister-class)

Comment: @AnuragUniyal If its not too much to ask would you mind posting the first method, only for the pusposes of gaining knowledge.

Comment: @Jimmy added recursive lister

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, no one has given a working answer to the File class addition to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but would this work?

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(/path/to/testdir/):
    listers = dict((dir, directory_lister(dir)) for dir in dirs)
    #now you can use:
    listers['j']
    listers['k']
    listers['l']
```

Comment: When I run this I get: 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'l'

Comment: ah change it to `directory_lister(os.path.join(root, dir))` instead of `directory_lister(dir)`

Comment: When I run this it returns a blank listers dictionary